# primefaces datatable mutiple selection checkbox: checking at least one item is selected

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces datatable with multiple checkbox selection and I can't find a way to check if there is at least one item selected using postValidate event

xhtml

```
<p:dataTable
        var="item"
        value="#{myBean.list}"
        selection="#{myBean.selectedItems}">
        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Item" />
            </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
        </p:column>                 
        <f:event listener="#{myBean.isSelectedItem}" type="postValidate" />     
</p:dataTable>
```

My Bean

```
 public void isSelectedItem(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
            HtmlDataTable table = (HtmlDataTable) event.getComponent();
            //no idea how to get checkboxes inside datatable
    }
```

How can I get elements inside datatable ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do it using your back bean method by checking if the selection list "selectedItems"  contains values or not.

Comment: thx for replying, but I've already tried your solution with no luck :(

Comment: @iconte: then you tried wrong. This works since I use this.

Comment: @Kukeltje Do you mind giving an example? I'm not sure but according to this link http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/multi-components-validator-in-jsf-2-0/ I believe the only way to get the value is using ComponentSystemEvent parameter. Backing bean attributes are null at this point